# How can I run JBoss Application Server and Apache on the same server?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, virtualhost, jboss

If multiple sites are hosted within a single server, how can someone able to use Apache for PHP and JBoss for Seam.

```
Example:  example.com  -> servered using PHP
          example2.com -> servered using JBoss
```

Comment: This will depend on whether the DNS records for those domains resolve to the same IP address (and would need to be served with name-based virtual hosting) or if they are set to resolve to separate IP addresses. Give us this information, and we can give you a good answer for how to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, the DNS records resolve to the same IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have to use the same IP address, you will need name-based virtual hosting in combination with a reverse proxy. For instance, you could use Apache in front of JBoss and set one name virtual host to example.com:80 and configure it as you normally would with mod_php.

For example2.com:80, configure a 2nd Apache name virtual host, but use mod_proxy to set Apache up to proxy requests to JBoss configured and listening on some other port (like 8080). This isn't too hard to get working. [This article](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies), plus the Apache documentation, of course, will be helpful.